# Copy specific files in SBT

Tags: scala, sbt

How would you create an sbt task to copy specific files (or file patterns) to a specific directory?

(For example, to copy `client/target/foobar.js` to `dist/js` and `server/target/web/public/*.*` to `dist/assets`).

I do not want to write a plugin to achieve this, but using an existing plugin is OK.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want it to be a separate task, you can start with the `copyResourcesTask` in [`Defaults.scala`](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/0.13/main/src/main/scala/sbt/Defaults.scala#L917):

```
  def copyResourcesTask =
    (classDirectory, resources, resourceDirectories, streams) map { (target, resrcs, dirs, s) =>
      val cacheFile = s.cacheDirectory / "copy-resources"
      val mappings = (resrcs --- dirs) pair (rebase(dirs, target) | flat(target))
      s.log.debug("Copy resource mappings: " + mappings.mkString("\n\t", "\n\t", ""))
      Sync(cacheFile)(mappings)
      mappings
    }
```

and modify it (just change `mappings` to the ones you want, and the tasks you depend on). Alternately, modify mappings in an existing task. See [Mapping Files](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Detailed-Topics/Mapping-Files.html) in documentation.